# Error while using Google Maps in Flutter App

Tags: flutter, google-maps

I try to use google-maps inside my flutter app but, I am getting this error every time I try to debug my code.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find play-services-maps-17.0.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-maps/17.0.0/play-services-maps-17.0.0.aar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 39s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: can you please share the github link? So i can see where is the problem

Comment: I will be grateful              https://github.com/sabahya3/Google-Maps-Flutter/tree/master

Comment: I just updated the answer it will fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please go to file -> android/app/build.gradle

and edit minSdkVersion from 16 to 21

```
    defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.example.google_maps"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
}
```

Comment: Nothing happened bro , I face the same error even after I followed your fixes

Comment: are you using emulator or physical device?

Comment: I tried both and neither worked!

Comment: made some changes to your github, Accept the pull request and then try running the code... BTW the same code is working for me.

Comment: if you still facing any error, edit the question with the complete error output

Comment: I cant find your pull request !

Answer (score 0):

According to it's document you should set the minSdkVersion in android/app/build.gradle:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 20
    }
}
```

Also add this code in the main file :

```
void main() {
  if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
    AndroidGoogleMapsFlutter.useAndroidViewSurface = true;
  }
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Configuartion link : https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter#android

Note: Please, check your Internet connection and, try a VPN!

Comment: Nothing happened bro , I face the same error even after I followed your fixes +1

Comment: I updated my answer. I hope my answer be helpful for you.

Comment: I changed the code , and I used vpn too , but still not working.